# Webpack for SRI rules

Tags: webpack, http-headers, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using the SonarWhal scanner and getting errors for [SRI](https://sonarwhal.com/docs/user-guide/rules/rule-sri/) on my scripts. We are using webpack to generate the bundles. I'm new to webpack and am hoping I can get some pointers on getting this to work.

[Roman01la's Github project](https://github.com/roman01la/webpack-sri/blob/master/index.js) seems to have a great start, but it only outputs the hash to the console. It hasn't been updated in a few years.

If I have a webpack.config.js with plugins:

```
plugins: [
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash].css',
}),
WebpackSRIPlugin,
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: false,
    template: 'Views/Shared/LayoutTemplates/LayoutTemplate.cshtml',
    chunks: ['lib', 'app'],
    filename: '../Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml'
}), more config
```

what is the trick to hooking that up with HtmlWebpackPlugin?

note: I added [an issue on the github project](https://github.com/roman01la/webpack-sri/issues/1), but I'm not expecting to get an answer there.

Comment: https://github.com/waysact/webpack-subresource-integrity#readme

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find that one when I was searching. It's great to know it already exists